# How to get CKA_ID from public/private Key pair of USB Token?

Tags: c++, cryptography, cryptoapi, hsm, pkcs#11

I have a USB token contain certificate, public/private key pair, how can i get

```
#define CKA_ID
Key identifier for public/private key pair (default empty).
```

From PKCS 11 document using C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First find the certificate with `CKO_CERTIFICATE`. (`C_FindObjectsInit, C_FindObjects, C_FindObjectsFinal`)

2.Get the CKA_ID using `C_GetAttributeValue`